# Linking a html button with python script

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have two codes. One HTML code and other python script. I wanted to link the submit button to link with my code to send mail to the recipient. I searched into most of the websites, but I am not being able to send the message that I have typed in the box.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="Msg">Type your Message</label>
        <input type="text" name="Msg" />
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <button type="submit"> Send Mail</button>
</div>
```

Python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request
from flask_mail import Mail,Message

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = "smtp.gmail.com"
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'Id@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = '******'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False

mail = Mail(app)

@app.route("/")
def create():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/index.html")
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message1 = request.form['title'];

    print ('message1')
    msg = Message('Hello', sender = 'Id@gmail.com', recipients = ['Id@gmail.com'])
    msg.body = message1
    mail.send(msg)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `action` when you define the form tag. Something like this:

```
<form action="/submit" method="post">
<div>
    <label for="Msg">Type your Message</label>
    <input type="text" name="Msg" />
</div>
<div>
    <button type="submit"> Send Mail</button>
</div>
```

And in the route decorator specify the submit action name, check if the message is coming and send email:

```
@app.route("/submit", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    message1 = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message1 = request.form['Msg']
    if message1:
        print(message1)
        msg = Message('Hello', sender = 'Id@gmail.com', recipients = ['Id@gmail.com'])
        msg.body = message1
        mail.send(msg)
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Don't forget to use csrf token on production while handling forms.

Comment: its not working. Can you please provide some other solution. Or any other live example with which I can send mails on the click of a button. I am new to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not clear answer, I don't know your output error, but you should add POST method into index route and add action attribute in your html form:

```
@app.route("/index", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message1 = request.form['title'];

    print ('message1')
    msg = Message('Hello', sender = 'Id@gmail.com', recipients = ['Id@gmail.com'])
    msg.body = message1
    mail.send(msg)
    return render_template("index.html")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run()
```

And add this into html form:

```
<form action="/index" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label for="Msg">Type your Message</label>
        <input type="text" name="Msg" />
    </div>
</form>

<div>
    <button type="submit"> Send Mail</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Did not get you. Can you please provide detailed ans. Wouls be much appreciated. I need to send mail on the click of a button. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to send mail by another method I personally use mailgun api www.mailgun.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your codes I think. I will do my best to describe it clearly. It is not only about your codes but some habits in flask and website.

### 1 routes of index and /

Never do like that render same template with 2 separated routes. You should do like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'] )
@app.route('/index.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
```

### 2 set the action in the form

Just like the answer above.

### ps

In fact, there is no differences between render a page or send a email in a `submit button` in a form, for they are all post the data to server and let the sever do (return a page or send a mail)